# How to fully uninstall Bitcoin Core on Macm2, and should I run a server as well as external HD

Tags: mac

does anyone know how to fully uninstall Bitcoin Core from a mac m2?
Also, I have a 1tb external hard drive, should I get an AWS server to run Bitcoin Core? I am doing it locally and it is still eating up my memory. So I need to fully uninstall and reinstall on my external hard drive. I also need help deleting all system data from running it without my external HD.
very appreciative of any and all help

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do? It sounds like you might prefer moving your Bitcoin directory to the external wallet rather than completely uninstalling?

Answer (score 0):

**Remember to always backup your wallet and any important data.**

The blockchain data is stored in a data directory. By default, it's located in `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`. Delete this directory to remove all blockchain data. You can do this through the terminal or Finder.

```bash
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/
```

Delete Configuration Files: Remove any remaining Bitcoin configuration files. These are usually in the home directory and can be hidden. Use the following command in the terminal to delete them:

```bash
rm -rf ~/.bitcoin/
```

After performing these steps, empty your Trash to permanently delete the application and associated files.